# Creating multiple lists depending on previous lists item (cyclic definition)

Tags: python, list

I need to generate multiple lists but element i for the first list depends on elements i-1 of the last list, as shown in the code below:

```py
# a, b, c are lists of the same size
# foo() and bar() are just functions that returns a float

a = [...]
b = [...]
c = [...] 

# definition of lists
a[i] = a[i-1] + c[i-1]
b[i] = foo(a[i])
c[i] = bar(b[i])
```

My implementation so far:

```py
a = []
b = []
c = []

for i in range(300):
    # a_0 is the initial value for a[0]
    a.append(a_0 if i == 0 else a[i-1] + c[i-1])
    b.append(foo(a[i]))
    c.append(bar(b[i]))
```

I feel there is a more elegant way to do this. Also in my case I have 18 lists, so the code is not the most readable.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, THAT code isn't going to work, because `len(a)` is 0.  I'll post a suggestion below.

Comment: good catch, I fixed it

Comment: You say you have 18 lists. But do you have a different function to update each list, or do `foo` and `bar` alternate?

Comment: @gimix Yes, I have a different function to update each list

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting a list of lists, so that you could go with two nested loops. But if the functions are different, you would need to create also a list of functions... So probably my idea is not worthwhile

Answer (score 1):

Remember that x[-1] always gives you the last element of `x`.  So, just pre-fill your first elements and you have a simple loop:

```
a = [a_0]
b = [0]
c = [0]

for _ in range(300):
    a.append( a[-1] + c[-1] )
    b.append( foo(a[-1]) )
    c.append( bar(b[-1]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You can't iterate over `range(len(a))`, because `a` is empty at the moment. You need to iterate over some sequence representing the *final* length of `a`/`b`/`c`.
2. You don't really care about arbitrary elements of the three lists, only the *last* element of each.

As such, you can initialize `a_0` to some value, then simply append values to each list. `a_0` can then be updated to reflect the value to be added to `a` on the *next* iteration.

```
a_0 = ...
for _ in range(10):
    a.append(a_0)
    b.append(foo(a[-1]))
    c.append(bar(b[-1]))
    a_0 = a[-1] + c[-1]
```